# Is "to have one's head in the sky" a valid English idiom?

Tags: idioms, spoken-english

Is "to have one's head in the sky" a valid English idiom like "to have one's head in the clouds"?

It took me too long remember this. Or rather, to become conscious of it. In the future, I shouldn't

> Why did it take me so much time to remember this? Or rather, to become
>   conscious of it? **Perhaps because I always had my head in the sky.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least in US English, heads are often many places.  Often heads are in the clouds (dreamer), but it is not unheard of to say that someone has their head in the sky if, for example, they aspire to become an aircraft pilot.

Comment: Yes, in the clouds is the usual idiom.

Comment: Head in the clouds, but nose in air (if someone is acting arrogant)

Answer (score 1):

"This can't be love. I get no dizzy spells,
my head is not in the skies" (Rodgers/Hart)

If it's not an idiom, it is at least part of the Great American Songbook.
Or maybe Mr. Hart was simply looking for something to rhyme with "sighs" and changed the well-known idiom from "clouds" to "skies", hoping that everyone would understand.

Answer (score 0):

Head in the sky means to me, you're aware and know what’s  around you but you don’t care because you're in your own element or just chilling in your own head. Connecting your mind, body and soul.